# Java - выдаёт ошибку ХЗ HELP!

Tags: java

В чём проблема?? Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Ошибка -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: GuessGame.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
```

Код -

```
class GuessGame {
Player p1;
Player p2;
Player p3;
public void startGame() {
    p1 = new Player();
    p2 = new Player();
    p3 = new Player();
    boolean p1isRight = false;
    boolean p2isRight = false;
    boolean p3isRight = false;
    int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println("I’m thinking of a number between 0 and 9...");
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Number to guess is " + targetNumber);
        p1.guess();
        p2.guess();
        p3.guess();
       int gp1 = p1.number;
        System.out.println("Player one guessed " + gp1);
       int gp2 = p2.number;
        System.out.println("Player two guessed " + gp2);
       int gp3 = p3.number;
        System.out.println("Player three guessed " + gp3);
        if (gp1 == targetNumber) {
            p1isRight = true;
        }
        if (gp2 == targetNumber) {
            p2isRight = true;
        }
        if (gp3 == targetNumber) {
            p3isRight = true;
        }
        if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
            System.out.println("We have a winner!");
            System.out.println("Player one got it right? " + p1isRight);
            System.out.println("Player two got it right? " + p2isRight);
            System.out.println("Player three got it right? " + p3isRight);
            System.out.println("Game is over.");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Players will have to try again.");
        }
    }
} }

class Player {
int number = 0; // where the guess goes
public void guess() {
    number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println("I’m guessing " + number);
} }

public class GameLauncher {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
    game.startGame();
} }
```

Comment: а как ваш файл называется?

Comment: @pavel Называется GameLauncher.java - http://imgur.com/a/LP9C5

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Решено!!!** - Там с названием всё было правильно... Проблема в том, что компилятор первым class GuessGame запускать хотел и после изменения параметров запуска компилятора на public сlass launcher всё заработало. Благодарю за уделение времени на мою тему :)

Comment: Компилятор компилирует, он ничего не запускает. Вас стоит отметить решением ответ @zed

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev написано про запуск компилятора.

Answer (score 2):

Исключение говорит о том, что у класса `GuessGame` нету метода `main`. По всей видимости, вы назвали файл с приведенным в вопросе кодом `GuessGame.java` и пытаетесь его запустить. Но по соглашению, в Java метод `main`, с которого стартует приложение, должен быть у класса, имя которого совпадает с именем файла.

Чтобы решить проблему, вам надо переименовать ваш файл в `GameLauncher.java`, т.к. именно у класса `GameLauncher` вы определили метод `main`.

Comment: Вот, смотрите - https://imgur.com/a/LP9C5

Comment: @MartinChobanyan у меня ваш код работает без ошибок: http://imgur.com/UcY7TU8 Запускаете через меню в IDEA, как на скриншоте?

Comment: @MartinChobanyan попробуйте разнести классы по файлам, чтобы соблюдалось правило *"Один класс - один файл"*.

Comment: Да, разобрался... Там в параметрах компилятора...